# Whats are the options to transform a event-driven tornado application into a threaded or otherwise blocking system?

Tags: python, tornado

I have inherited a rather large code base that utilizes tornado to compute and serve big and complex data-types (imagine a 1 MB XML file). Currently there are 8 instances of tornado running to compute and serve this data.

That was a wrong design-decision from the start and I am facing many many timeouts from applications that access the servers.

I'd like to change as few lines of code as possible in the legacy code base because I do not want to break anything that has already been tested in the field. What can I do to transform this system into a threaded one that can execute more xml-computation in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> transform this system into a threaded one that can execute more xml-computation in parallel

If there are enough Tornado instances to saturate the computational resources, moving to a threaded model will probably not gain much performance. Getting rid of blocking code however helps with connection timeouts.

Another option is getting rid of all asynchronous code and using `tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication`. That way, you can run the application on a threaded WSGI server. Features that are not available in WSGI mode are listed [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#wsgi-and-google-appengine).

Answer (score 1):

Use Tornado to just receive non-blocking requests. To do the actual XML processing you can then spawn another process or use an async task processor like celery. Using celery would facilitate easy scaling of your system in future. In fact with this model you'll just need one Tornado instance.

@Eren - I don't think that the computational resources are getting saturated. It would just be that more than 8 requests are not getting processed simultaneously as Tornado would right now be serving requests in blocking mode.

Comment: My point was, if the majority of workload is parsing big XML files (CPU intensive), moving to threaded model would not be a gain over the usual Tornado IOLoop instance. More like a reminder since we don't know much about the code. With 'blocking mode', do you mean each Tornado instance running as a single wsgi thread? That would be horrible, although I don't know why anyone would do such a thing :)